# How to use $ with externally loaded javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm trying to load an external javascript file that uses jquery but references it with '$'. Through some digging around, I've cobbled together the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    (function($) {
        $.getScript('https://cdn.timekit.io/booking-js/v2/booking.min.js', function() {
            var widget = new TimekitBooking();
            widget.init({
                app_key: 'test_widget_key',
                project_id: '1234'
                // optional configuration here.. (read more under: configuration)
            });
        });
    })( jQuery );       
});
```

I've then enqueued this script in the footer. However, I keep getting the error 'TypeError: $ is undefined' in line 45 of the loaded script and lines 10 and 15 of this one.

Is this the best method of achieving what I want, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add `jquery` as a dependency for the script? e.g. `wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script', 'path/to/script/file', array( 'jquery' ) )`

Comment: I hadn't, but have done so now, unfortunately without success. :(

Comment: "*$ is undefined' in line 45 of the loaded script*" - at the top of the script, add `window.$ = jQuery;` and see if the issue persists. And regardless yes or not, I think the problem is in the script itself and has nothing to do with PHP - do check the page source, though - see if jQuery is actually loaded on the page.

Comment: Thanks very much. `window.$ = jQuery;` seems to have done the trick.